# How to access file properly to append text (MD5hash)?

Tags: c#, file, md5, streamwriter

I am trying to append a MD5 hash (based on the length of a file) of a file after the file is closed. I am doing that like this:

```
string filePath = "myPath";
string fileName = "myFileName";

File.Delete(filePath + fileName);
if (!File.Exists(filePath + fileName))
{
    using (var sw = File.CreateText(filePath + fileName))
    {
         sw.Write("Stuff to write");
    }
}
using (var sw = File.AppendText(filePath + fileName))
{
    sw.Write(ctx.GetMD5HashFromFile(filePath, fileName));
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work since the file is not closed properly in between the two using statements. I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '
[filePath + fileName] because it is being used by another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

How can I compute the MD5 hash properly and append the text without getting an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are opening the file twice in your second piece of code:

```
using (var sw = File.AppendText(filePath + fileName))
{
    sw.Write(ctx.GetMD5HashFromFile(filePath, fileName));
}
```

`ctx.GetMD5HashFromFile` probably opens the file to create the hash; but you already opened it to append data. So create the hash before the `File.AppendText` `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the file on creation, try:

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
      using (var sw = File.CreateText(filePath))
      {
            sw.Write("Stuff to write");
      }
 }
 FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filePath);
 string hashString = ctx.GetMD5HashFromFile(file);
 file.Close();

 File.WriteAllText(filePath, hashString);
```

only open the file for reading when getting the hash:

[C# calculate MD5 for opened file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405705/c-sharp-calculate-md5-for-opened-file)

Comment: The using block closes the stream on exit

Comment: sorry, mistested it. new answer. but Bas' answer should be the one

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use Sha1Sum instead of MD5 which is very old and unsafe

This function return the value in format "C61211674FD03175FEC87A9C01F39F72376CE104"

```
    public static string MakeSha(string Mystr)
    {
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider Crpyt = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] buf = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Mystr);
        return BitConverter.ToString(Crpyt.ComputeHash(buf)).Replace("-", "").ToUpper();
    }
```

PS: Don't forget to add in using statement the following using System.Security.Cryptography;

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I would say less safe the Sha1Sum. Sha1Sum gives and result of 40 bytes MD5 32 bytes. IT's harder to break a code 40 bytes then 32 bytes

Comment: @Bas Brekelmans  I advise to use Sha1Sum which is more secure the anser was already given by you!

Comment: @IsmailGunes no one is trying to break a code; this is used as a checksum.